# unable to load JSON data in 'data' array

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

when I call this function the array 'data' is showing empty square brackets, it is not giving me any errors though
here is the code :-

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Networking {

    var data = [Item]()

    let tVC = TableViewController()

    let url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"

    func getCoinData(url: String) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {

                    let coinJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                    for i in 0..<coinJSON.count{
                        let coinName = Item(bitJSON: coinJSON[i])
                        self.data.append(coinName)
                        self.tVC.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the actual response is not just empty JSON?

Comment: I did, the response is success and showing JSON data but the 'append' to 'data' is not happening

Comment: The coinJSON is a JSON object, not array. Use coinJSON.arrayValue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
Change your url, method is "Get" and your mapping model.

```
public static func getArrayInformation(completionHandler: @escaping (APIResponse) -> Void) {
    let url = "your url"
    let params: Parameters = ["username": "admin",
                             "password": "1234"]

    Alamofire.request(url,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: params,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json"])
        .responseDecodableObject(keyPath: nil, decoder: JSONDecoder(), completionHandler: { (handler: DataResponse<[Your Object Array]>) in
            completionHandler(handler.result.value ?? [Your Object Array]())
        })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why you reload Table every loop iteration , and instead Loop use `Map`

```
class Networking {

    var data = [Item]()

    let tVC = TableViewController()

    let url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"

    func getCoinData(url: String) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {

                    let coinJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

                   data =  coinJSON.map({ (coinJson) -> Item in
                        return Item(bitJSON: coinJson)
                    })


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tVC.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }
                else {
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good points both, but this doesn't look like an answer to the OPs question.

Comment: yes not answer , code above have no error and code in question have no error

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19970548)

Comment: Sorry Didn't understand you what is your need @FlameTrap